# How do I write a .txt file on my macOS Desktop while running an iOS app on XCode?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift3, xcode8

I want to get coordinates from a UIImageView and transfer them through serial into an Arduino. I was thinking about writing the coordinates into on a .txt on my MacOS Desktop, which can be parsed through regular C++ file handling. **This is only during development.** The final app will probably use Bluetooth.

I've looked into the Foundation API Reference, and it all lead to file directories on my iPhone instead of file directories on my MacOS. Is it possible to retrieve information from XCode and store it on MacOS instead of iOS?

Or, am I just better off transferring this data to the Arduino through Bluetooth?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you need to exchange data between iOS and macOS periodically (also when the app is distributed) or do you need to access the data temporarily (during development) to process it in macOS?

Comment: @vadian data temporarily during development

Comment: Then save the data into the app's container and copy it manually to the desktop. The data of the simulator are available in the file system of macOS.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for this. May I know where the app's container is?

Comment: Look into ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need this *during development* when running on an *actual* iPhone device, you could try 2 options:

**HTTP**. You could launch a simple web server on macOS and then send the desired data using plain HTTP from the iOS end.

Python provides `SimpleHTTPServer` but I don't think it supports PUT or POST commands yet. But [this one](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997) does.

**Sockets**. On your macOS, listen on an arbitrary TCP port (e.g., `8000`) and redirect the output to a text file:

```
nc -k -l 8000 > ios.txt
```

and you can test it like this (on macOS):

```
echo foo | nc localhost 8000
```

Finally, on the iOS end, send your data using standard sockets.